# Как на PyQt5 убрать фон картинки

Tags: python, pyqt5, изображения, pyside2

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на PyQt5 убрать белый фон картинки. Например есть картинка jpg [image: Исходник]

Нужно получить, то же но без белого фона в формате png
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно маску применить, поменяв белый цвет на прозрачный, но это может в коте сделать что-то прозрачным, кроме того, это работает если будет определенный код пикселя: https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/48211-How-to-change-QPixmap-color-from-black-to-red?p=217194#post217194 Или пройтись циклом по всем пикселям и поменять указанный цвет пиксели на прозрачный. Могу накидать пример в ответе, но не гарантирую, что не обойдется без каких-либо проблем :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге сделал используя [createHeuristicMask](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#createHeuristicMask), но это вышло больше из-за метода тыка, пока с масками игрался, чем знаниями по маскам :)

Пример:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


app = QGuiApplication([])

pixmap = QPixmap("cat.jpg")
pixmap.setMask(pixmap.createHeuristicMask(Qt.transparent))
pixmap.save('cat.png')
```

Результат (в PyCharm):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это вариант лучше чем мой) Тут нет ареала точек белых (с цветом около белый) вокруг кота.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QHBoxLayout,
                               QLabel, QApplication, QMessageBox)
from PySide2.QtGui import QPixmap, QColor, QImage
import traceback


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap("cat.jpg")
        image = pixmap.toImage()
        image = image.convertToFormat(QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        for y in range(0, image.height() + 1):
            for x in range(0, image.width() + 1):
                print(image.pixelColor(x, y).getRgbF())
                if image.pixelColor(x, y).getRgbF() == (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0):
                    image.setPixelColor(x, y, QColor(0, 0, 0, 0))

        pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)

        lbl = QLabel(self)
        lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)

        hbox.addWidget(lbl)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.move(300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Red Rock')
        self.show()


def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    # pyqt визуализация ошибок
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))
    print(text)
    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    sys.exit()


sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Example()
    app.exec_()
```

Где-то примерно так =) Спасибо, gil9red!

PS. Способ выше, так сказать "в лоб" достаточно долгий, т.к. идет перебор по пикселям, наиболее оптимальный для меня показался следующий, например есть картинка:

[image: Исходник]

к ней можно применить следующий код (:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication, QPixmap, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


app = QGuiApplication([])

pixmap = QPixmap("test.jpg")

for i in range(1,6):
    for k in range(1,6):
        for j in range(1,6):
            pixmap.setMask(pixmap.createMaskFromColor(QColor(250+i, 250+k, 250+j)))

pixmap.save('out.png')
```

т.е. применение createMaskFromColor по цветам близким к белому.

Comment: Если есть варианты лучше, просьба предложить. Или замечания по коду, буду рад ревью =)

Comment: Вы молодец, что сами сделали (+1) :) У меня вышло проще, но как это работает я не смогу объяснить (в отличии от вашего кода) :D

Comment: Ну уж сам))) Допилил вашу ссылку заменяя "::" на точки)))

Comment: Чтобы переписать код с одного языка на другой нужно в обоих языках разбираться и приложить усилия, поэтому не скромничайте ;)

Answer (score 1):

Для этих целей есть хороший сервис и я не могу не поделиться им,
так как сам им пользуюсь.

Загрузите изображение в удалить фон
https://www.remove.bg/upload

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]